# Struggling to show then hide success alert using Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue website and am new to Vue.

I have a test button which when clicked I want to display a Bootstrap 4 (not Bootstrap-vue) success `alert` then for it to remove after x seconds.

I have the easy part done, showing it but I can't seem to get the hang of hiding it after a certain amount of time.

Code I have:

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="testToast">TEST BUTTON</button>

        <div v-if="testButClicked" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Item successfully added to your cart
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>
```

**Code**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                testButClicked: false
            }
        },

        methods: {
            testToast() {
                this.testButClicked = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1.3s ease;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

I have created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97k4ofu1/2/)

I have tried adding a `watch` to say when its displayed `setTimout` to set value back to false, then I tried using the below code set in a global file so it can use it globally as I would like to use it on other pages but couldn't get it work at all nor could I find help on how to get it work

```
Vue.effect('toast', {
    enter: function (el, insert, timeout) {
        // insert() will actually insert the element
    },
    leave: function (el, remove, timeout) {
        // remove() will actually remove the element
    }
})
```

Then I tried the following HTML, again it would transition in correct or remove

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in" :duration="{ enter: 1500, leave: 2000 }">
```

I don't want button press which is all the solutions I seem to be finding online, I know jQuery to do this but can't get it to work in Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using a `setTimeout` on the method is to add a watch and include a `setTimeout` there.  This has the advantage that *anything* causing this value to be set will be cleared after the requesite time, and it can't be triggered multiple times (as it will only react when the value is changed to `true`).  Modified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wp4980r5/1/).  The changed code block (I used a 1s timeout just because I'm impatient during testing ;)):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      testButClicked: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testToast() {
      this.testButClicked = true;
    }
  },
  watch:{
    testButClicked(val){
      if (val){
        setTimeout(()=>this.testButClicked=false,1000);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually figured it out and was about to post i had when i noticed you had the same solution i did except i didn't add mine in the watch

Answer (score 3):

You can just add the `setTimeout` in the function. Regardless of if this function is a click handler or not.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      testButClicked: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testToast() {
      this.testButClicked = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.testButClicked = false
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.alert {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 15px;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1.3s ease;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="testToast">TEST BUTTON</button>
  <br><br>
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div v-if="testButClicked" class="alert" role="alert">
      Item successfully added to your cart
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```